# Unity Particle Effects On Canvas

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, canvas

Is is possible to use the particle effects system on your UI elements.  For instance on the Canvas?  I'd like to make some animations and whatnot for my UI elements and the particle system would be nice, but it doesn't seem to support this.  Am I correct in assuming this?  Is there another solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well what you could do would be letting a Camera render the Particle effects on a different layer to a [`RenderTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html) and show it in a [`RawImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html) in your UI.

Combined with a hint from [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150726/how-can-i-make-my-cameras-rendertexture-output-have-a-transparent-background): By default `RenderTexture` has only a colordepth of 24-bit but we need 32-bit for alpha the simplest way is just generating one via code:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class RenderParticlesEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here reference the camera component of the particles camera
    [SerializeField] private Camera particlesCamera;

    // Adjust the resolution in pixels
    [SerializeField] private Vector2Int imageResolution = new Vector2Int(256, 256);

    // Reference the RawImage in your UI
    [SerializeField] private RawImage targetImage;

    private RenderTexture renderTexture;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!particlesCamera) particlesCamera = GetComponent<Camera>();

        renderTexture = new RenderTexture(imageResolution.x, imageResolution.y, 32);
        particlesCamera.targetTexture = renderTexture;

        targetImage.texture = renderTexture;
    }
}
```

---

My example Hierachy looks like this:

[image]

- Add a new [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) `ParticleEffect` for the particles.

  [image]
- The `ParticleCamera` is a new `Camera`. Here

  - remove the `AudioListener` component since there may only be one in the Scene.
  - Set ClearFlag to `Solid Color` and set a desired color. Particles won't be completely transparent but always bloat a bit the background color of this camera on the edges. Make sure the alpha is set to `0`.
  - Set `Culling Mask` to only `ParticleEffect` so this camera renders nothing else from the scene

    [image]
  - And the `RenderParticleseffect` component
- On the normal `MainCamera` remove `ParticleEffect` from the `Culling Mask`

  [image]
- Set the `Particles` to the layer `ParticleEffect` so now it will only be rendered by the `ParticleCamera`

  [image]
- Finally reference the target `particleImage` from the UI in the `RenderParticlesEffect` component on the `ParticlesCamera`

  [image]

Result:

[image]

It doesn't matter if the Canvas is `Screenspace Overlay` or not.

Comment: this was helpful for me in Unity 2020 without using URP

Answer (score 4):

By default the render mode setting is selected as Screen Space- Overlay. 
This render mode places UI elements on the screen rendered on top of the scene due to which the particle effects are not visible.

You have to change the render mode setting of Canvas in the inspector to Screen Space- Camera and also give reference of camera in the scene to render camera property of canvas.
In this render mode the Canvas is placed a given distance in front of a specified Camera.

Comment: I was aware of this.  I attempted and it worked, accept my objects were flying through my UI.  I suppose I'll have to get it working somehow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just have to add one thing.

Built-In Pipeline, LTS 2021. I followed these instructions, then added the Particle Material to the RawImage in the canvas. Then in the particles camera, I set the Solid Color to pure black and the alpha to 0. This removed all the bleed effect and got things looking just how I wanted. Then I just set the width and height in the Rect Transform of the RawImage to scale the particle effect how I wanted. This took some trial and error, so I thought I'd hope to save someone else the pain.

Thanks for the great guide, Hugo!