# How can I add a camera over a canvas ui?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The main goal is to show a main menu with a preview window that show live camera for example the player camera.

I created a Render Texture named it MainMenuRenderTexture.
This screenshot show the Canvas settings :

[image: Canvas]

This screenshot show the GUI Camera settings :

[image: GUI Camera]

And rawimage I added over the Canvas.
I want to show on the rawimage another camera I have not the GUI Camera but another camera I have in the hierarchy.

[image: Raw Image]

Comment: Screen space canvases are always last and draw on top of everything, always always always every time, no exceptions.

Comment: Use layers! In [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58834101/7111561) I described exactly what you are trying to do: Just put the UI itself on a different layer so your UI camera will **only** render the UI, the preview Camera will render everything **except** the UI. In your case you can also skip the 32bit depth part since you want no transparent background for your preview I guess.