# Tried to render particles from a different layer to show it on my UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, particles

I'm trying to show particles' effect on my UI. Then I came across this post: [Unity Particle Effects On Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830542/unity-particle-effects-on-canvas)
And I followed every step, but the particles are not shown on the canvas when I click play for some reason.

[My Particle Camera components][1]
[My Hierachy][2]

I just followed the steps shown in the post, so my script is basically identical:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Particle_Camera_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here reference the camera component of the particles camera
    [SerializeField] private Camera particlesCamera;

    // Adjust the resolution in pixels
    [SerializeField] private Vector2Int imageResolution = new Vector2Int(256, 256);

    // Reference the RawImage in your UI
    [SerializeField] private RawImage targetImage;

    private RenderTexture renderTexture;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!particlesCamera) particlesCamera = GetComponent<Camera>();

        renderTexture = new RenderTexture(imageResolution.x, imageResolution.y, 32);
        particlesCamera.targetTexture = renderTexture;

        targetImage.texture = renderTexture;
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you for reading this.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/alNAL.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtbtH.png

Comment: Consider using this brilliant alternative: https://github.com/mob-sakai/ParticleEffectForUGUI

Comment: @Iggy - Thank you for the comment, I will try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried @Iggy method and it seems to work fine. I just had to download a package then I was ready to go. https://github.com/mob-sakai/ParticleEffectForUGUI

I don't know why this post got a dislike, but whoever disliked could at least tell me why, so I can at least improve.