# Unity UI mask does not work on children with different Canvas component and particles

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

The UI's structure are as follows:

```
--Canvas C (Render mode: Screen Space - Camera; sorting layer is s1)    
----Image A (with a UI Mask; it's a viewport in a `ScrollView`)    
------Particle P (Particles Effect, Renderer's Sorting Layer s2 is above s1)    
------Image B (with Canvas Component, Sorting Layer s3 is above s2)
```

The UI mask on A does not work on P and B. How can I make it work?

A custom UI mask shader that work with different `Canvas` component, sorting layers, and non-UI children(`Particles`) would be a perfect solution. However my knowledge about shader is very basic. I would like to know what direction or keywords should I look for. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's the sorting layers .. is there really a new `Canvas` component on `Image B`? Also Particles are not part of the UI System and therefore not affected at all by a UI.Mask. maybe this helps you: [Unity Particle Effects on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58834101/7111561)

Comment: @derHugo Thank you! Yes there is a `Canvas` on `Image B`. The link you mentioned is a good plan, however not a good one for me, because I have multiple particles under Image A, and since it's in a scroll view with layout group, the transform dynamically changes. If we take out `Particle P`, we need to handle each of the transforms and that could be troublesome.

Comment: A custom mask shader that work with another `Canvas`, sorting layers, and non-UI sprite would be a perfect solution. However my knowledge about shader is very basic. I would like to know what direction or keywords should I look for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this.

In simple words, on the child that wants to be masked but with a different canvas, use a custom UI/Default material with the following parameters.

[image]

Important parameters are:
1 Stencil ID, should be the same with the one with Mask component.
2 Stencil Comparison, 3 means "Render pixels when their reference value is equal to the current value in the stencil buffer."

The built-in Mask also achieved it by changing the stencil parameters for each child gameobject. They just forget to change so for child with different Canvas or did this on purpose.

Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html#comparison-operation-values