# How to have Unity Particle System render behind other GameObjects

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system, unity2.0

I am using Unity Particle System to generate confetti when a user has finished a level. However, I am not able to have the particles appear behind the gameobjects. Any help would be appreciated.

I added the particle system to a gameobject, created a camera for it and have the camera for the particle gameobject. From there, I set the depth of the gameobject to 0 so that it renders behind the other gameobjects. Did not work.

**UPDATE****

I have tried the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58834101/19998452). However, I am unable to set the camera alpha to 0. I am able to put the particle system to an object but not able to set the camera alpha to 0. How can I do that?

This is what I am seeing.
[Particle Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jC8W.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the layer of particle system "Particle" and make two cameras, 1 for particle and set occlusion layer to "Particle" and other camera to have all layers except the "Particle" and set its priority higher than the previous camera.

Comment: I tried that. However, the particle is behind the panel rather than behind the objects within the panel.

Comment: Then give "Particle" layer to panel also, this will fix your issue.

Comment: I tried that already and it didnt work

Comment: Sameer Ahmed: refer to update did

Comment: Can you explain what happened after setting panel to layer "Particle"

Comment: Are you saying I should have a particle panel, set that to layer Particle? If so, I tried that and the panel is behind the the winnerpanel