# Unity Camera with RenderTexture problem, how to get the right output?

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

I have a scene need to display a 3d module to ui layer, so i use a secondary camera to render it to     a RenderTexture, but when i set a background to the ui layer ,i found that the content is wrong, because the alpha channel is not what i expect

In order to describe my problem more clearly, I created a [demo](https://github.com/tsx1453/UnityRenderTextureWithCameraDemo)

the content: in the center has the backgorund color, this is what i don't want, i want the center is fully white
[image: the content]

the 3d object: a cube with opaque material and sphere with transparent material
[image: the 3d object]

the renderTexture's alpha channel:
[image: the renderTexture's alpha channel]

I tried use colormask to disable alpha output, but the ui layer background size is smaller than my 3d model's content, so where there is no background it is invisible.

Update at 2023-2-15-17:49
this is the problem in my project, the character's hair has some transparent part, i use a camera with renderTexture to display it on Ui layer, but the hair's transparent part make some mistake
[image: real scene]

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830542/unity-particle-effects-on-canvas I think though the transparency is a general shader issue .. the render texture will always receive something and not only be transparent at the given spots ...

Comment: I use the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830542/unity-particle-effects-on-canvas, my problem is the alpha channel's data make the ui content display  wrong, and i want to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Set the RenderTexture's Color Format to ARGB32.
2. Make sure the background of the UI layer is fully opaque.
3. Enable Alpha Clipping in the material of the 3D object, and set the Alpha to the desired value.
4. Set the RenderTexture's Clear Flags to "Depth Only", so that the background color will not be taken into account.

Comment: Let me know if that fixes that

Comment: my 3d mdoel has some transparent parts,so alpha clipping is not  suitable for me，and the ui background is fully opqaue, but on ui layer the model's content is large than background, our ui is designed like this